# Where can I download the list of references listed in a paper?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics, reference-managers

I would like to retrieve the references listed in a paper, as a RIS file or any format that I can import in my reference manager.

Is there a way to do that?
I can retrieve the list of papers which listed that paper, but not the list of their references.
I looked on the journal's page. Any other service?

Comment: Web of Science does this just fine, as likely do other similar search engines. The button isn't as obvious as the one for the citing papers, but it is there.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for the quick reply! Will check that

Comment: On the new WoS pages, over on the right side of a given listing is links for both the Citations and References. Clicking one brings up the appropriate listing, with options to mark and export.

Comment: https://excite.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/excite

Comment: excite of Stuttgart university really works bad for me

Answer (score 5):

If your university has a subscription to *Web of Science*, you could do the following:

1. Search for the relevant paper (here is an example with the keywords 'health diplomacy'):
   [image]
2. Click on the number of references at the right (the red circle in the screenshot above)
3. Tick all references and click on "Export", choose your preferred document type (e.g. RIS or BibTeX etc.)

[image]